# Who can I hire to investigate a possible airflow blockage in my attic?

Tags: ceiling, condensation

Had a new roof replaced last year, tear off/replace.  Also had a new slider door replacing old one installed last year.  I am noticing what appears to be staining where the ceiling meets the wall. Could replaing the roof may have disturbed the insulation to stop air flow in soffit?  Who do I hire to check this out for me?

Comment: It's unlikely that the roofing job affected the insulation. What makes you think it's not a roof leak?

Comment: It does not have a ring like a water spot, just moist looking.  A builder who was over to give me an estimate for a new deck said he thought that there was a problem with the air flow and that possibly while banging around on the roof may have caused the insulation to slide down and block the air flow from the soffit.  I have cathedral ceilings.  Who would I hire to look into the attic above the cathedral ceiling to see if that's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order of preference I'd probably call these folks:

- A trusted handyperson (likely least expensive)
- An insulation contractor (likely most knowledgeable, but more expensive)
- A building or remodeling contractor (certainly capable, but probably most expensive)

You don't really need any particular credentials. You just need someone with a brain in their head and insurance.